# Depositing the same check after it's returned

Tags: united-states, check, checking-account

So I wrote a check to myself to transfer some money from one of my account at Wells Fargo to Bank of America.
The problem is, I used wrong account to withdraw the money (checking instead of saving), and I didn't have enough balance in that account to make the transfer, so check is returned.

I used BofA mobile app to deposit the check, now I'm wondering if I can used the exact same check to make the transfer via bofa mobile app again. I already made a money transfer from Saving to Deposit at Wells, so this time my check should be cleared.

Asking this, because I don't have any other check and don't want to wait another week to get some new checks.

Comment: Can't you just transfer the money electronically without using any physical check?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can redeposit the check using the same application. I would again go through the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after making sure that the saving account of Wells Fargo has enough balance, you can provide the same check and get the cash transferred. It should be noted that check bounce is actually a matter of legal consequences and always enquire regarding the available balance. Also, get an idea regarding the future debits to that particular account before you write a check of that account.